# How can i compare two dates in the same column and get the oldest?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date-comparison

I am new with SQL and i recived a good task.
The task is:
I have two tables, one called TICKETS end other called LOGS.

Tickets:
ID | Ticket | Open_Date
10 | 40000 | 2015-03-01 11:00:00
11 | 40001 | 2015-03-01 12:00:00
12 | 40002 | 2015-03-01 13:00:00
13 | 40003 | 2015-03-01 14:00:00
14 | 40004 | 2015-03-01 15:00:00

Logs:
ID | Ticket_id | Time_Stamp | Description
01 | 10 | 2015-03-01 11:10:00| In Progress
02 | 10 | 2015-03-01 11:15:00| In Progress
03 | 10 | 2015-03-01 11:20:00| Transfered
04 | 11 | 2015-03-01 12:10:00| In Progress
05 | 11 | 2015-03-01 12:15:00| Transfered
06 | 11 | 2015-03-01 12:20:00| In Progress
07 | 12 | 2015-03-01 13:05:00| Transfered
08 | 12 | 2015-03-01 13:10:00| In Progress
09 | 12 | 2015-03-01 13:15:00| In Progress
10 | 13 | 2015-03-01 14:05:00| Transfered
11 | 13 | 2015-03-01 14:10:00| Transfered
12 | 13 | 2015-03-01 14:15:00| In Progress
13 | 14 | 2015-03-01 15:10:00| Transfered
14 | 14 | 2015-03-01 15:15:00| In Progress
15 | 14 | 2015-03-01 15:20:00| Transfered

As showed in the tables, i have many logs to a single ticket. What i need to do is find the first log with description "In Progress" and get its date(the oldest). If it comes after a log of "Transfered" get the date of the log "Transfered" as "Open_Date" of the ticket and then get the date of the first log "In Progress".

The query that was give to me brings just the first "In Progress" log:

```
`Select 
Tickets.ticket, 
Tickets.Open_Date,
Logs.Description,
Logs.Time_Stamp
From
Tickets LEFT JOIN Logs ON Tickets.ID = Logs.Ticket_id
WHERE
Logs.Time_Stamp = (Select MIN(Logs_2.Time_Stamp)
                   From Logs AS Logs_2
                   Where Logs_2.Description = 'In Progress')
And Logs.Time_Stamp < '2015-03-01 14:30:00'
And Logs.Time_Stamp > '2015-03-01 10:00:00'
Group By
Tickets.ticket, 
Tickets.Open_Date,
Logs.Description,
Logs.Time_Stamp`
```

I hope I have been clear on my problem :)
Could someone help me?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you dont actually want value from preceding / next row?
(http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/  )

but query ID / Ticket_ID and sort by date?
( [sql query to get earliest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393573/sql-query-to-get-earliest-date) )